# I want to give every new registering user a unique key apart from password field for external use

Tags: user-registration

I want to give every new registering user a unique key apart from the password field and other fields in the WordPress database table for external use. I want to use this key for identification of every registered user in my app. SO that the user in this database also use the app. Please, anyone, help me to create a unique key for every user in WordPress.

I will get this key using this http://wordpress.com/wp-json/v1/authorization/

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try **user_register** hook for this purpose, because it gives you user's id, which you need to add user meta. 
According to WP documentation: 
*This action hook allows you to access data for a new user immediately after they are added to the database. The user id is passed to hook as an argument.*

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    /*
       Create your **$unique_key** here and add it as user meta below
    */

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'unique_key', $unique_key);

}
```